# How to manually input decimal value into z-coord in QGIS

Tags: qgis, z-value, nodetool

If I want to manually input a decimal value to Z-coord in QGIS, there's no effect. Only integer values are saved in nodes editor. Operating system Ubuntu 18.04, QGIS 3.6, locale: poland, data and money format: polish.

[image: cannot input decimal value]

Comment: What type of field is the z column?String?float?...

Comment: @FranRaga That's the Vertex Editor, not an attribute table.

Comment: In QGIS 3.4.1 on Windows 10, I have no trouble inputting and changing decimal places of Z coordinates in the Vertex Editor. Please [edit] your question and provide some more details: What version of QGIS, and what operating system are you using? What file format (shapefile/CSV/geopackage etc)? What geometry type (point/line/polygon)?

Comment: One difference I noticed is that my system uses the period for a decimal separator, and yours uses the comma. Just as a test, try overriding your system locale (Options > Settings > General) and choose a locale that uses the period as its decimal separator (eg English UnitedStates). If that fixes the problem, it's definitely a bug and you should make a bug report at https://issues.qgis.org.

Comment: Thank You CSK. That was solved a problem. I will report that bug.